# Find a hyperplane not intersecting $S$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling with the following problem:

Let $K$ be an infinite field, $V$ an $n$-dimensional $K$-vector space, $S \subset V$ a finite subset with $0 \notin S$.
Prove that there exists a subspace $W \subset V$ of dimension $n-1$ such that $W \cap S = \emptyset$.

I think this is quite obvious geometrically, however I am not able to prove this. I tried both by induction on $n$ and on the cardinality of $S$, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: (Minor note: you surely require that $0 \not \in S$.)

Comment: You are right, I will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by proving that for every $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ ($n>1$) and any finite set $S$ with $0 \not\in S$, there's a $1$-dimensional subspace of $V$ that does not intersect $S$. (You'll need to use the fact that our field is infinite here.) Now we induct.

Suppose $V$ an $n$-dimensional vector space has a $k$-dimensional subspace that doesn't intersect $S$ with $k < n-1$. Call it $W$. Now consider the $n-k$-dimensional vector space $V/W$; its dimension is bigger than $1$, and the image of $S$ is still a finite set that doesn't contain $0$. So by the first step, we have a $1$-dimensional subspace of $V/W$ that doesn't intersect the image of $S$. Lift this up to a $(k+1)$-dimensional subspace of $V$ that doesn't intersect $S$; then by induction, there's a subspace of $V$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n-1$ that doesn't intersect $S$, which is what we wanted all along.